# How to ignore delimiter when double quote is inside a field

Tags: csvhelper

I'm having a hard time parsing the following string.

```
8545448,"user@test.com","KR!:!받은메일함!*!EN!:!Inbox!*!CN!:!收件箱","'양념게장단'전차도? 님이 공유: \"\" 춤출지, 유지할지 자문해야\"\"","2022-01-01 04:29:40","info@twitter.com","외부",\N,"/data5/5@1641011380251.eml",\N,"user@test.com!:!이메일!:!","",""
```

It clearly consists of 13 fields, but CsvParser recognizes it as 14 fields. Probably because delimiter exists inside double quotes.

```
"'양념게장단'전차도? 님이 공유: \"\" 춤출지, 유지할지 자문해야\"\""
```

Below is the code that is running into the problem.

```
//
// CSVHelper
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var parser = new CsvParser(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = false,
}))
{
    writer.WriteLine(data);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    parser.Read();
    fieldCount = parser.Count; // 14
}
```

However, if I used a regular expression, I was able to get the number of fields normally.

```
//
// Regular Expression
Regex CSVParser = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
String[] fields = CSVParser.Split(data);
fieldCount = fields.Length; // 13
```

Is it possible to solve this problem by using a specific property of CsvConfiguration in CsvHelper?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that CsvHelper defaults to escaping a " with another ".  In your data, the " is escaped with \ .  You just need to set your configuration to use a backslash for the escape.

```cs
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var parser = new CsvParser(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = false,
    Escape = '\\'
}))
{
    writer.WriteLine(data);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    parser.Read();
    fieldCount = parser.Count; // 14
}
```